# Replicate `df.expanding().min()` in polars

Tags: pandas, python-polars

In Polars what is the best way to replicate the `expanding` functionality of pandas?

Here is some dummy data I am using:

```
data = {
    "prices": [100, 99, 101, 98, 103, 109, 102,78, 101],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # or pl.DataFrame for my code at the bottom.
```

I want to calculate the minimum from row 0 to the current row.

In **pandas** this is easy:

```
df.expanding().min()
```

In **polars** I found two suggested solutions:

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        # Not working using lazy dataframe
        Min1 = pl.col("prices").rolling_min(window_size=df.height, min_periods=1),
        # considered "unstable" as per documentation
        Min2 = pl.col("prices").cumulative_eval(pl.element().min())
    )
)
```

Both solutions are not optimal because

- Min1 cannot be used in lazy dataframe as it requires knowledge about df
- Min2 is considered unstable and non-performant according to the polars docs.

**What is considered a good solution for this kind of problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note.** In general, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4799) for the expanding functionality of pandas.

For your specific case, you can simply use [`pl.Expr.cum_min`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cum_min.html).

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("prices").cum_min())
```

```
shape: (9, 1)
┌────────┐
│ prices │
│ ---    │
│ i64    │
╞════════╡
│ 100    │
│ 99     │
│ 99     │
│ 98     │
│ 98     │
│ 98     │
│ 98     │
│ 78     │
│ 78     │
└────────┘
```

Comment: Thx. This was rather obvious, but somehow I got lost in the not so obvious solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `pl.Expr.cum_min` is definitely the way to go here. For other similar use cases you can use generic [`pl.Expr.cumulative_eval()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cumulative_eval.html) function, but it comes with a warning:

> This functionality is considered unstable. It may be changed at any
> point without it being considered a breaking change.

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("prices").cumulative_eval(pl.element().min()).alias('min')
)

┌────────┬─────┐
│ prices ┆ min │
│ ---    ┆ --- │
│ i64    ┆ i64 │
╞════════╪═════╡
│ 100    ┆ 100 │
│ 99     ┆ 99  │
│ 101    ┆ 99  │
│ 98     ┆ 98  │
│ 103    ┆ 98  │
│ 109    ┆ 98  │
│ 102    ┆ 98  │
│ 78     ┆ 78  │
│ 101    ┆ 78  │
└────────┴─────┘
```